# My dedicated server keeps getting very slow that it fails to load the application

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, performance, server-crashes

I have an application running on Windows Server 2008, running IIS 7.5, SQL Server 2008, 4GB RAM from brinkster.

The problem is, every couple of days I get the same 10,000 calls that the system is very slow, and its not operating properly, then after 30 minutes of that it just fails to load. I try to access the server from the remote desktop connection but I can't access it.

The only way it I can get it working again is to call the support at brinkster and have them do a manual reboot of the server.

After that it works well for some time, and the it re-crashes after some time. Support over there, are not helping a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth logging the performance counters and taking a look at them.  Take a look at these posts from the Windows Server Performance Team:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/01/10/preparing-to-troubleshoot-part-one.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/05/25/basic-troubleshooting-toolkit.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/05/13/two-minute-drill-logman-exe.aspx

What's running on the server?  How heavy is the load?  If it works fine and then slows down to unusable my guess would be either connections are coming in faster than they can be serviced or memory is leaking (or just being heavily used) and your server is paging to death.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out why the system slows down that much. Are jobs running on the database that are too resource-intensive or do you have a bug in some app causing a memory leak or too many spawning processes? Set up performance monitor to see what resources (CPU, disk I/O etc.) are used over time and check the logs and see if there are error reports about missing resources.

Without any more input we can't help you any more.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is dedicated and if you have the ability to do so then I'd suggest booting up a live Linux CD and running memtestp on the machine to see if it's working in a stable state. If it does seem ok I'd suggest you've got a OS/application issue such a memory leak or odd/wrong drivers. Basically you need to check your hardware is ok first then narrow it down, leave the OS running on its own for a while without applications to see if that's stable as it is, then fire up your applications one are a time until you've found the culprit. Oh and use the management tools to look for CPU and memory hogs too of course.

Answer (score 0):

A few more details would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

1. How many users are on it at a given point of time?
2. Check the task manager to see what is eating up resources.
3. You mention crashing. Is it blue-screening? Google the error code.

Answer (score -6):

Get a decent server. Seriously. Sounds like a low end machine (4gb ram is low desktop those days) and likely your server just gets totally overloaded. Check event logs. how many discs do you have? As a SQL Server handling tonds of calls that sounds really pathetic.

Comment: haha take it easy tomtom!! you sound reasonable, the ram dose not get 50% full, when it first restarts, it works great, but after a while the performance just crashes!!

Comment: Tom, just throwing hardware at it won't help at all if there is a software problem. A memory leak will even fill up 512 GB of RAM eventually, just a little bit later.

Comment: Yeah, but you dont say ´"a better car wont help" if you fail behind in racing with a stock fiat panda. A server that size is anything BUT a database server able to handle 10.000 reuquests.